# Consumer Stops Consuming Messages event with repeat being added at end of DAG

Tags: apache-kafka, project-reactor

**Problem Statment**

Kafka Receiver Stops Consuming Messages After some time with/without load. A pod restart fixes the issue.

**Consumer Config**

```
auto.offset.reset: earliest
max.poll.records: 5
max.poll.interval.ms: 500000}
session.timeout.ms: 300000}
enable.auto.commit: false
flux.limit.request.cap: 10
commit.batch.size: 100
commit.batch.interval.ms: 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms: 500
retry.backoff.ms: 5000
request.timeout.ms: 90000
```

**Code**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ReactiveKafkaConsumer implements KafkaConsumer {

    //the default is set to 4 as the max cpu allocation in kubernetes is 4.

    private ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<Integer, Long>> topicPartitionOffsetMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private KafkaReceiver<String, Result<FormatException, String>> backFillKafkaReceiver;

    @Value("${eh.consumer.realtime-flatmap-parallelism:4}")
    private int realtimeEhConsumerFlatMapParallelism;

    @Value("${eh.consumer.backfill-flatmap-parallelism:4}")
    private int backfillEhConsumerFlatMapParallelism;

    private KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties;

    @Value("${kafka.backfill.consumer.enable:true}")
    private boolean backfillConsumerEnable;
    private KafkaReceiver<String, Result<FormatException, String>> kafkaReceiver;

    // This holds reference to a subscription on inboundKafkaFlux that could be
    // cancelled using dispose()
    private Disposable realTimeDisposable;

    private Disposable backfillDisposable;

    private MessageProcessorOrchestrator messageProcessorOrchestrator;

    private ConsumerErrorHandler errorHandler;

    private Scheduler boundedElasticScheduler;

    private Scheduler parallelWorkScheduler;

    private long startTime;

    //
    @Value("${reactor.consumer.retry-attempts-for-kafka-receive:10}")
    private int numberOfRetryAttempsForKafkaReceive;

    @Value("${reactor.consumer.gap-between-retry-attempts-for-kafka-receive-seconds:3}")
    private int gapBetweenRetryAttempsForKafkaReceiveSeconds;


    public ReactiveKafkaConsumer(
            @Autowired KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties,
            @Autowired KafkaReceiver<String, Result<FormatException, String>> kafkaReceiver,
            @Autowired MessageProcessorOrchestrator messageProcessorOrchestrator,
            @Autowired ConsumerErrorHandler errorHandler,
            @Autowired Scheduler boundedElasticScheduler,
            @Autowired Scheduler parallelWorkScheduler,
            @Autowired KafkaReceiver<String, Result<FormatException, String>> backFillKafkaReceiver) {
        this.kafkaConsumerProperties = kafkaConsumerProperties;
        this.kafkaReceiver = kafkaReceiver;
        this.messageProcessorOrchestrator = messageProcessorOrchestrator;
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
        this.boundedElasticScheduler = boundedElasticScheduler;
        this.parallelWorkScheduler = parallelWorkScheduler;
        this.backFillKafkaReceiver = backFillKafkaReceiver;
    }

    public ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<Integer, Long>> getTopicPartitionOffsetMap()
    {
        return this.topicPartitionOffsetMap;
    }



    private Flux<Void> getKafkaConsumerFlux(KafkaReceiver<String, Result<FormatException, String>> reactiveKafkaReceiver,int flatmapParallelism)
    {

        return Flux.defer(reactiveKafkaReceiver::receive)
                .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> log.info("Subscribed to Kafka event stream={}", subscription))
                .doOnCancel(() -> log.info("Unsubscribing from Kafka event stream. Closing resources."))
                .doOnNext(r -> log.debug(
                        "Message received from topic name={}, partition={}, offset={}",
                        r.topic(), r.partition(), r.offset()))
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error occurred while receiving from kafka flux", e))
                .groupBy(r -> r.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
                .flatMap(partitionFlux -> partitionFlux.subscribeOn(boundedElasticScheduler)
                        .publishOn(parallelWorkScheduler)
                        .map(record -> processRecord(partitionFlux.key(), record))
                        .concatMap(this::commitOffset)
                        .onErrorResume(this::logUnknownErrorInChain)
                        .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(numberOfRetryAttempsForKafkaReceive, Duration.ofSeconds(gapBetweenRetryAttempsForKafkaReceiveSeconds)).transientErrors(true))
                        .repeat(),flatmapParallelism)
                .doOnError(this::logUnknownError)
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(numberOfRetryAttempsForKafkaReceive, Duration.ofSeconds(gapBetweenRetryAttempsForKafkaReceiveSeconds)).transientErrors(true));


    }


    @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
    @Override
    public void onMessage() {
        log.info("onMessage() is called on application main thread");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("shutdownHook to dispose kafkaReceiver subscription") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                log.info("[ReactiveKafkaConsumer:shutdownHook] ----> shutdownHook to dispose kafkaReceiver subscription is started");
                try {
                    close();
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    log.error("[ReactiveKafkaConsumer:shutdownHook] ----> Error occurred while disposing kafkaReceiver subscription", e);
                }
                log.info("[ReactiveKafkaConsumer:shutdownHook] ----> shutdownHook to dispose kafkaReceiver subscription is completed");
            }
        });

        realTimeDisposable = getKafkaConsumerFlux(kafkaReceiver,realtimeEhConsumerFlatMapParallelism).repeat().subscribe();

       
    }


    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {

        if (!realTimeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
            // buffer time for elements in the pipeline to be processed before shutdown
            log.info("Sleeping {} seconds for elements in the pipeline to be processed before closing the in-bound stream",
                    (kafkaConsumerProperties.getShutdownDelayMs() / 1000));

            Thread.sleep(kafkaConsumerProperties.getShutdownDelayMs() / 1000);
            // un-subscribe from in-bound kafka stream. Stop receiving any new elements.
            realTimeDisposable.dispose();

        }


    }

    private Mono<Tuple2<ReceiverOffset, Map<String, String>>> processRecord(TopicPartition topicPartition,
                                                                            ReceiverRecord<String, Result<FormatException, String>> record) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Map<String, String> kafkaHeaders = extractKafkaHeaders(record.headers());

        logDebugWithMDC(kafkaHeaders, log, String.format("kafkaHeaders extracted=%s", kafkaHeaders));

        try {
            return messageProcessorOrchestrator.process(record.value().get(), record.topic(), kafkaHeaders)
                    .doOnSubscribe(s -> logDebugWithMDC(kafkaHeaders, log,
                            "Submitted for async processing with record offset={} from partition={} in topic={}",
                            record.receiverOffset(), topicPartition.partition(), topicPartition.topic()))
                    .then(Mono.just(Tuples.of(record.receiverOffset(), kafkaHeaders)))
                    .onErrorResume(e -> handleError(e, record, kafkaHeaders))
                    ;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            return handleError(e, record, kafkaHeaders);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Commit offset.
     *
     * @param offsetHeadersTupleMono
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Mono<Void> commitOffset(Mono<Tuple2<ReceiverOffset, Map<String, String>>> offsetHeadersTupleMono) {
        return offsetHeadersTupleMono
                .flatMap(offsetHeadersTuple -> {
                    ReceiverOffset offset = (ReceiverOffset) offsetHeadersTuple.get(0);
                    Map<String, String> headers = (Map<String, String>) offsetHeadersTuple.get(1);
                    Mono<Void> commitResponseMono = offset.commit();
                    long endTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
                    // get or create the partition-offset map for the given topic
                    ConcurrentMap<Integer, Long> partitionOffsetMap = topicPartitionOffsetMap.computeIfAbsent(
                            offset.topicPartition().topic(), k -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

                    // save partition and its offset in the map
                    partitionOffsetMap.put(offset.topicPartition().partition(), offset.offset());
                    logDebugWithMDC(headers, log,
                            "Commit offset={} for partition={} on topic={} time_taken={} ms, {} ns to process the record",
                            offset,
                            offset.topicPartition().partition(),
                            offset.topicPartition().topic(), (endTime / 1000000), endTime);
                    return commitResponseMono;
                });
    }

    

    private Mono<Tuple2<ReceiverOffset, Map<String, String>>> handleError(Throwable e, ReceiverRecord<String, Result<FormatException, String>> record,
                                                                          Map<String, String> headers) {
        logErrorWithMDC(headers, log, "Error occurred while processing record.Submitting error to error handler", e);
        errorHandler.handleError(e, record, headers);
        return Mono.just(Tuples.of(record.receiverOffset(), headers));
    }

    private Mono<Void> logUnknownErrorInChain(Throwable e) {
        logUnknownError(e);
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    private void logUnknownError(Throwable e) {
        log.error("Unknown error occurred in kafka flux", e);
    }
}



  public EventMessageProcessorOrchestrator(@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                                             @Autowired Unmarshaller eventUnmarshaller,
                                             @Autowired DomainEventProcessor domainEventProcessor) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.eventUnmarshaller = eventUnmarshaller;
        this.domainEventProcessor = domainEventProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> process(String message, String topic, Map<String, String> kafkaHeaders) throws JsonProcessingException {
        try {
            logDebugWithMDC(kafkaHeaders, log, "Message received={}", message);

            ObjectNode node = objectMapper.readValue(message, ObjectNode.class);

            Optional<Mono<Void>> eventProcessedMono = Optional.ofNullable(eventUnmarshaller.unmarshal(node, kafkaHeaders))
                    .map(event -> domainEventProcessor.process((EventEnvelope<?>) event, topic, kafkaHeaders));

            return eventProcessedMono.orElseGet(Mono::empty);

        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
            logErrorWithMDC(kafkaHeaders, log, String.format("Invalid message format=%s ", message), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    ------------------------------------------------------------



       @Override
    public Mono<Void> process(EventEnvelope<?> event, String topic, Map<String, String> kafkaHeaders) {

        if (!featureFlagHelper.isFeatureEnabled(FeatureFlagConstants.X)) {
            
            return Mono.empty();
        }

        String entityType = kafkaHeaders.get(HeaderConstants.ENTITY_TYPE);
        Type type = Type.getTypeByLabel(entityType);

        switch (Objects.requireNonNull(ipsEntityType)) {
            case A
                return x.processA(event, topic, kafkaHeaders);
            case B:
                return x.processB(event, topic, kafkaHeaders);
            case C:
                return x.processC(event, topic, kafkaHeaders);
            case D:
                return x.processD(event, topic, kafkaHeaders);
            case E:
                return x.processE(event, topic, kafkaHeaders);
            case F:
                return x.processF(event, topic, kafkaHeaders);
            default:
                logErrorWithMDC());
        }

        return Mono.empty();
    }





 public Mono<Void> processA(EventEnvelope<?> event, String topic, Map<String, String> kafkaHeaders) {
//        logDebugWithMDC(kafkaHeaders, log, String.format("EventEnvelope=%s", event));

        DomainEvent<X<X>> eventBody = (DomainEvent<X<X>>) event.getBody();

        final X x = eventBody.getEntity().getDomainAttributes();

        A type = getType(eventBody);
        HashMap<String, String> requestHeaders = getRequestHeaders(kafkaHeaders);

        if (ipsEventType != null) {
            switch (ipsEventType) {
                case CREATED:
                        return process.getHeaders()
                                .flatMap(authorization -> {
                                    requestHeaders.put(HeaderConstants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY, authorization);
                                    return outputPort.getEntity();
                                })

                                .flatMap(candidateWorkflow -> publishCustomSearchDocuments(candidateWorkflow,
                                        new CandidateOfferEntity(), new CandidateWorkflowMarketingEntity(),
                                        new CandidateWorkflowTodoEntities(), ipsEventType, topic, kafkaHeaders))
                                .doOnNext(entity -> logDebugWithMDC())
                                .doOnError(e -> logErrorWithMDC())
                                .onErrorResume(Mono::error);
                    }



@Override
    public Mono<CandidateWorkflowEntity> getCandidateWorkflowByCandidateWorkflowId(Long candidateWorkflowId, Map<String, String> headers) {

        FilterCriteria filterCriteria = new FilterCriteria();
        KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue();
        keyValue.setKey(SOME_KEY);
        keyValue.setValue(String.valueOf(SOME_ID));
        filterCriteria.getKeyValue().add(keyValue);

        return Mono.just(filterCriteria)
                .publishOn(boundedElasticNestedFluxScheduler)
                .flatMap(criteria -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> restClient.getData(criteria, SOME_CONSTANT, headers)))
                .publishOn(parallelWorkScheduler)
                .map(dppCandidateWorkflowEntityMapper::mapEntityToCandidateWorkflowEntity);
    }
```

**Code Description**
There is a parent flux with Kafka Receiver and then there are nested fluxes for each method. all the errors related to business logic are handled then and there with logging and offset is committed always.
Let me know if more details are needed